# Converting string for year, e.g. "2021" to categorical in pandas-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, types

In pandas-profiling, my DataFrame has a variable with 4-digit integers representing years. This variable is being interpreted as numeric. I would like to have it be treated as categorical if the value lies between 1800 and 2300.
Sample data:

```
              Qual        Year  Marks   Inst       Id
        0     Bachelor's  2008  51      N.C.L      330133
        1     Higher Cert 2016  56      P.J.H      359823
        2     Master's    2008  89      Y.J.X      360098
        3     Master's    2016  88      T.X.K      371786
        4     National    2011  90      O.X.W      313117
```

When I run

```
python
        from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
        profile = ProfileReport(data, title="Academic Qualifications Profiling Report", config_file = "config_gdis.yaml")
        profile.to_file("Profile Demo\Academic Qualifications Profile Report.html")
```

I get

```
        YearOfPassing
        Real number (ℝ≥0)
```

I'm expecting

```
        YearOfPassing
        Categorical
```

I've tried adding the line between asterisks in the typeset_relations.py file but it doesn't work. The other three lines are from the original pandas-profiling code.

```
python
        def numeric_is_category(series, state):
            *return (1800 <= pd.Categorical(pd.to_numeric(series,  errors="coerce").fillna(0).astype(np.int64) <= 2300))*
            n_unique = series.nunique()
            threshold = config["vars"]["num"]["low_categorical_threshold"].get(int)
            return 1 <= n_unique <= threshold
```

Comment: Please post sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Try `df['YearOfPassing'] = df['YearOfPassing'].astype('category')`

Comment: Raghava, all I have to work with is the serialized version of the DataFrame, and I want to apply it to any DataFrame. This is within pandas-profiling which infers datatypes using visions.